# Accessibility on back to top link

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, tabindex

I am working on a web page which is relatively long (4+ pages). For ease of use I have added the *back to top* link at the bottom of the page.

I would like to know, whether I can skip this link from screen readers or assistive tools by using aria-hidden="true" and tabindex="-1". Does this fail the accessibility criteria ?

Since the back to top arrow is visible at the bottom of the page, is it necessary to make this link available for screen reader users ?  So far my understanding is *home* key serves as back to top for keyboard/screen reader users.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: An accessibility consultant (and screen reader user) I've worked with maintains that developers should try to give all users the same experience—not create multiple different good experiences. With that principle in mind, I would recommend *not* hiding the back to top link from screen readers.

Comment: @sean : Thank you for your comment. Is it mandatory to focus on any element on the back to top link click ? If Yes, what is the best practice ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be focusing on any one single user's experience. For example, if you have that 'Back to Top' link in logical spots, it should **not** be taken out of tab order because you're only considering one type of user experience. A the same time, accessible features shouldn't impede on a normal experience.

That said, on a pure development basis, links should receive focus so it does fail since it's not completely operable.

Answer (score -1):

[WCAG 2.1.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/keyboard.html) is pretty clear on this topic.

> **All** functionality of the content is operable through a keyboard interface...

It doesn't say "most" functionality.

The <kbd>home</kbd> key works for mouse users too so why should they also have the ability to click on the "back to top" link and no one else?

Comment: **aria-hidden** is introduced to hide elements from screen readers. Is it against WCAG to hide focus-able elements given that we could also hide elements using aria-hidden ?

Comment: Yes, it violates WCAG to hide interactive elements from some users but not all users.  If you use `display:none` so that the element is hidden from everyone, that's ok.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#fourth